# How can I list all ERC20 transfers to a specific ETH address?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan

I'm trying to pull up a list of all incoming transfers to an ETH address.  The research I've done seems to indicate this can be done via etherscan using the logs module. (https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/logs).

However I do not know how to produce the parameters the API requires.

As an example, say I want to list all MATIC transfers to an address.

The MATIC contract address is 0x7D1AfA7B718fb893dB30A3aBc0Cfc608AaCfeBB0
The destination address is 0xBcef3db86DCcDa6CA1fdBba91Abd525c8D3BF363

How do I take this information and produce the topic_0 and topic_1 parameters for the API request?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: You might want to take a look at a data indexing solution such as [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research. topic_0 is the hash of the event signature.  I used https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html to generate the hash.

In this case the event I want is Transfer(address,address,uint256) and the hash is ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef

topic_1 is the 1st parameter of the method, which is the from address.  I don't want to specify this.  Instead I want to specify the to address which is topic_2.  topic_2 must be 66 chars, so I padded the destination address with zeros.  So topic_2=0x000000000000000000000000Bcef3db86DCcDa6CA1fdBba91Abd525c8D3BF363

This gives me a list of all ERC20 tokens transferred to the destination address.  Now I need to figure out how to tell what token and how many were transferred for each record.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should be pretty easy to do using the ERC-20 transfers API endpoint (https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc20-token-transfer-events-by-address).

For your above query, I'd do:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x7D1AfA7B718fb893dB30A3aBc0Cfc608AaCfeBB0&address=0xBcef3db86DCcDa6CA1fdBba91Abd525c8D3BF363&page=1&offset=10000&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=[INSERT API KEY HERE]
```

This will list out all transfers of the MATIC token to or from that address (and it's then trivially easy to filter out all the `from` transactions if you want to, so you only get the incoming transactions *to* this address).

Answer (score 0):

Moralis provide such API.
Give it just the chain and the wallet, and your good to go.

https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-wallet-token-transfers

Answer (score 0):

If it's on ethereum mainnet, you could use a service like Dune or Google Big Query to get all transaction/token transfers to addresses. The lag time for data ranges but no greater than 10 minutes.